What is the easiest way to get a male Litleo?
I kept wondering why I was only running into female Litleo in the wild, then I realised the gender ratio is like 12.5 male to 87.5 female. I since tried breeding as my understanding is that the gender is supposed to be random. But I only got female Litleo hatching as well. What would be the best way to attempt this?

From Pokemon Emerald onward and before Gen 9, if the Pokémon at the head of your party had the Cute Charm ability, there was a 66% higher chance of you encountering a Pokémon of the opposite gender to your front Pokémon.
Sadly, this effect was removed in Scarlet/Violet, so I think you have no way to improve your odds of a male Litleo. Just keep trying.

I didn't realise the cute charm odds were removed, that makes sense now. So the odds of breeding a male egg vs encountering a male litleo in the wild are the same?

@FrontEnd yes, same chances
